# Maven 3.0.5 vs 3.1.1 vs 3.2.1

Tags: java, maven

Today I've visited [official Maven website](http://maven.apache.org/) and was surprised to see 3 versions listed there: 3.0.5, 3.1.1, and 3.2.1

I am currently using 3.0.5, and would like to know if I should upgrade to a newer version.

Unfortunately, there is not a single word on the website about what is different between versions, and whether it is recommended to upgrade, and if upgrade to what version.

Can anyone point to the relevant resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Codehaus shut down in April 2015, some of the links in the historical release notes (e.g. in 3.2.1) are broken. You can browse them at:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=12316922

One important point for consideration: upgrading Maven will upgrade the *default* version of core plugins. And almost everything interesting about Maven is done in the plugins (hence why you won't find many Earth shattering changes in the release notes of Maven itself).

If you are relying on default plugin versions, you need to look at the plugin release notes as well as just the maven version. The release notes for 3.2.1 don't include the changes that come along with Wagon 2.6, for example.

I suggest not to rely on maven's plugin version defaults as it is too easy for colleagues to use slightly different Maven versions leading to inconsistent builds due to plugin differences.

If you're not doing so already, I suggest to explicitly specify your maven version in your pom; e.g.:

```
<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0.5</maven>
</prerequisites>
```

Then add a dependency on versions-maven-plugin and run

```
mvn versions:display-plugin-updates.
```

This will give you a list of all the updates available to plugins for your version of maven. Google to find out if there are any changes of interest. Of course you can choose to upgrade only some plugins, but regardless specify all your plugin dependencies explicitly.

Comment: `upgrading Maven will upgrade the default version of core plugins.` This is true if you wrongly not define your plugin versions in your projects...

Comment: khmarbaise -- very true, I recommend not to rely on the defaults in my answer

Answer (score 5):

There are two key things to know for software developer using Maven:

1. Maven 3.0.5 is just a security fix for maven 3.0.4 and nothing more. This version is fully compatible with what you had before. So if you have <=3.0.4 then 3.0.5 is the easiest way to go.
2. Some maven plugins may fail to work properly with Maven 3.1.x or 3.2.x. This happened to "flyway" for instance (which we use on our project). And I've seen some reports of other plugins failing as well. So if you can do a quick-switch, test, and nothing goes wrong, I guess you are okay with the latest version.

In other aspects 3.1.x and 3.2.x are just an evolution of maven.
Releases 3.1.x and 3.2.x introduce more changes to internal maven mechanics than to user experience. They are now using SLF4J internally, changed some libraries implementations, some CDI mechanisms....
However some user-friendly features are there as well. Like "version ranges" support.

All in all.... I'm starting to think toward gradle :)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read the [release notes](http://maven.apache.org/release-notes-all.html); for example, 3.1.1 has the bug fixes

```
[MNG-5459] - failure to resolve pom artifact from snapshotVersion in maven-metadata.xml
[MNG-5495] - API incompatibility causes Swagger Maven Plugin (and others) to fail under Maven 3.1.0
[MNG-5499] - maven-aether-provider leaks Sisu Plexus and ObjectWeb classes onto the classpath when they are not required
[MNG-5500] - help for --legacy-local-repository option explains _maven.repositories instead of _remote.repositories
[MNG-5503] - Maven 3.1.0 fails to resolve artifacts produced by reactor build
[MNG-5509] - org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.DefaultWagonManager should set User-Agent
```

**EDIT:**

If you then scroll down, you might notice

Release Notes - Maven - Version 3.1.0 (since 3.0.5 only)
Bug

```
[MNG-3131] - Error message is misleading if a missing plugin parameter is of a type like List
[MNG-5016] - A mirror's layout setting should default to 'default' since thats' the only layout supported lay in maven 3
[MNG-5206] - plexus container never disposed
[MNG-5208] - Parallel (-T option) multi module build fires wrong "project failed event"
[MNG-5209] - MavenProject.getTestClasspathElements can return null elements
[MNG-5212] - DefaultPluginDescriptorCache does not retain pluginDescriptor dependencies
[MNG-5214] - Dependency resolution substitutes g:a:v:jar for j:a:v:something-else when something-else isn't in the reactor
[MNG-5233] - ArtifactMetadataRetrievalException from org.apache.maven.artifact.metadata is not anymore binary compatible.
[MNG-5258] - localRepository in settings.xml does not handle ~ as home.dir
[MNG-5261] - upgrade wagon version to 2.3 to fix issues with redirect
[MNG-5270] - README.bootstrap.txt says "Ant 1.6.5 or later" BUT 1.8 or later is needed
[MNG-5280] - Inconsistent order of repositories and pluginRepositories from profiles in settings (regression Maven 3)
[MNG-5289] - -Dmaven.repo.local not honored
[MNG-5312] - MavenProject.getParent intolerably slow when import scope used heavily
[MNG-5313] - Unnecessary DefaultModelBuilder.build overload
[MNG-5314] - DefaultModelValidator misuses String.matches
[MNG-5336] - Descriptor Reference for settings.xml is incorrect
[MNG-5387] - Add ability to replace an artifact in mid-build
[MNG-5390] - mvn -rf (no argument) results in NPE
[MNG-5395] - logger name for plugins should not be DefaultMavenPluginManager
[MNG-5396] - logger name for execution events should not be MavenCli
[MNG-5398] - scriptSourceDirectory in superpom is not prefixed with /usr/home/cmsslave/slave15/maven-site-staging/build/trunk/
[MNG-5403] - tar.gz release artifacts have wrong permissions on directories
[MNG-5418] - Can't activate a profile by checking for the presence of a file in $myProperty
[MNG-5430] - use wagon 2.4
[MNG-5444] - ModelSource API is not sufficient to resolve project hierachies
[MNG-5445] - Missing PathTranslator @Requirement in org.apache.maven.project.interpolation.StringSearchModelInterpolator
[MNG-5456] - Maven skips modules and reports success if parallel build encounters java.lang.Error
[MNG-5477] - "malformed POM" warning issued when no version in reporting section
```

Improvement

```
[MNG-4505] - use slf4j to control various logging frameworks
[MNG-5181] - New resolution from local repository is very confusing
[MNG-5239] - Maven integration developers would like to be able to override the maven logging appender.
[MNG-5245] - upgrade default plugins versions
[MNG-5338] - Accept a directory with -f/--file
[MNG-5350] - improve @threadSafe error message: tell which goal
[MNG-5399] - Upgrade version of maven-release-plugin in superpom to 2.3.2
[MNG-5400] - Upgrade version of maven-dependency-plugin in superpom to 2.5
[MNG-5402] - Better build number for git
[MNG-5480] - document in POM descriptor reference how urls are interpolated from parent
[MNG-5482] - Catch NoClassDefFoundError org/sonatype/aether
```

New Feature

```
[MNG-519] - Timestamps on messages
[MNG-5306] - for IDE embedding have ways of collecting model problems without failing the process
[MNG-5343] - Allow the use of JSR330 annotation in Maven extensions and plugins
[MNG-5344] - Allow the SLF4J loggers to be @Injected
[MNG-5354] - Integrate Eclipse Aether 0.9.0.M2
[MNG-5380] - Cannot preserve whitespace in Maven plugin configuration
[MNG-5381] - Restore MavenSession.getRepositoryCache()
[MNG-5382] - Add an IT for @Inject used in plugins
[MNG-5386] - Dispose of ClassRealms after invocation to prevent out of Permgen errors
[MNG-5388] - Restore embedded integration tests
[MNG-5391] - Update the default WAR plugin version to avoid version 2.3
[MNG-5393] - Look at Sonar's use of SLF4J and Logback
[MNG-5397] - Use SLF4J for logging
[MNG-5407] - Change MavenITmng1830ShowVersionTest to account for SHA1 as version
```

Task

```
[MNG-5279] - add CLI options to documentation
[MNG-5365] - Replace Aether's deprecated ConfigurationProperties with ConfigUtils
[MNG-5372] - remove classes that were added during Maven 3 alpha and beta but were deprecated before 3.0 final release
[MNG-5373] - Document the usage and benefits of JSR330
[MNG-5374] - Fix transfer listener after the JSR330 merge
[MNG-5375] - Document use of SLF4J
[MNG-5376] - Account for changes between the Apple and Oracle JDKs on OSX
[MNG-5453] - Update Maven 3 build to use Eclipse/Sisu
```

Wish

```
[MNG-5370] - separate artifact-handlers configuration from plugin bindings to default lifecycle
[MNG-5461] - rename _maven.repositories tracking file to _remote.repositories
```

Finally, 3.2.1 is documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html).

Comment: Yeah, I saw the bug fixes list.  Still does not answer the question, why bother with update from 3.0.5?  If you look carefully, it fixes 3.1.0 problems. And still not a word about 3.2.1 changes?

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak Added 3.0.5 to 3.1.0 release notes, and a link for the 3.2.1 release notes. You need to decide if they provide enough new features (or bug fixes) for you to upgrade.