# Detected Maven Version: 3.0.5 is not in the allowed range 3.2

Tags: java, maven, pmml

I am working with Maven and I am getting errors with compiling and building my project. It is the jpmml-project to evaluate some pmml file. Now I got this error:

> Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireMavenVersion failed with message: Detected Maven Version: 3.0.5 is not in the allowed range 3.2.

Check the link to see the image:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3r9d8g8l4r1zctp/maven_error.png?dl=0

Please help! I do not have too much experience with Java and Maven.

Comment: Type `mvn -version` from a command prompt.  What version of Maven are you running?

Comment: This is because of an old maven-version.

See this answer: [Codehouse shutdown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30581567/4796992)

Answer (score 12):

Your `pom.xml` contains a plugin called [enforcer](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/), that can define a [required maven version](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html). You need to install the mentioned maven version (3.2.*) and use it to compile the project.

Answer (score 10):

In case you can't or don't want to update Maven due to some reason but urgently need the build results there is also a way to bypass this check using the command line option:

```
-Denforcer.skip=true
```

It worked for me for Maven 3.0.4 and maven-enforcer-plugin 3.0.0-M1. Since you did not mention in your question if you need just to complete the build or complete it making the enforcer stage fixed, I propose this workaround as an answer as well.

Comment: Very handy when you're in a rush just for testing, thanks.

Comment: Saved my time, thank you. I work on couple projects that have different Maven and Java setup, and this option saved me from switching regularly between maven version from environment variables, Very useful command

Answer (score 7):

In intelliJ 2016.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04:

I had installed the latest with:
sudo apt-get install maven

Then just dig down to where IntelliJ hides which maven it will use:

```
File > 
Settings > 
Build, Execution, Deployment >
Build Tools >
Maven >
Maven_home directory (I didn't have this env variable set, so you can choose):
```

-Bundled (Maven 2)
-Bundled (Maven 3) (was the 3.0.5 and it was chosen)
-/usr/share/maven <--- where the newly downloaded maven lives (3.3.9)

I could have probably saved a little time and made a */etc/profile.d/maven.sh* file and defined:

**export MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven** after installing the latest with apt...

Answer (score 3):

`The error` means that your `maven` version is too old, you should upgrade your maven version to be grater than `3.2`

The maven download link

http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

then 
clean & compile

Comment: Actually, because this is an enforcer error, you need to use specifically 3.2, as newer versions won't pass the rule either.

Comment: Works fine with Maven 3.3.3. Is my computer broken or something?

Answer (score 3):

Go to Window > Preferences > Maven > Installations

Under Installation you will notice that the embedded version is 3.0.5

Add a new installation for 3.2

- Click Add
- Navigate to your maven 3.2 installation

Answer (score 1):

- Install latest version of Maven from http://maven.apache.org
- If you are using **Netbean IDE** then go to Tools -> Options -> Java -> Maven and just configure the installation path as bellow

  [image]
- Open your maven project in Netbeans and build it with dependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Whoever is maintaining this project should think about using an enforcer rule like this. Usually you say you need at least Maven 3.1.1 or higher but never bind to a fixed version. Apart from that Version 3.2 of Maven does not exist...3.2.1 is first 3.2.X release.

Comment: Maven Enforcer Plugin has its own version range syntax, which is more relaxed than the "standard" version range syntax. So, `3.2` is perfectly valid. See http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html

Comment: Based on the error message it says something different.

Comment: Please elaborate. Over here, 3.0 is less than 3.2, which is the *minimal* supported version